# how to get nested elements in a REST API result with android studio?

Tags: android

my android app sends datas to a REST API and the communication is going on well. But the problem is many elements i would like to access are nested inside others elements at two,three or fourth degree like this :

```
[
{
"account": {
  "accountId": 0,
  "accountType": {
    "accountTypeId": 0,
    "libelle": "string"
  },
  "user": {
    "actif": true,
    "activationCode": "string",
    "address": "string",
    "blacklist": true,
    "cni": "string",
    "cniState": 0,
    "creationDate": "2021-04-01T05:23:21.838Z",
    "email": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastLogin": "2021-04-01T05:23:21.838Z",
    "lastName": "string",
    "msisdn": "string",
    "nickName": "string",
    "nombre": 0,
    "pays": "string",
    "platform": "string",
    "profil": "User",
    "profile": {
      "code": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "id": 0,
      "libelle": "string",
      "resource": [
        {
          "code": "string",
          "id": 0,
          "libelle": "string",
          "status": true
        }
      ],
      "status": true
    },
```

as you see, they are nested elements like **code** inside **profile** element which under **user** and user is under **account** element. so what i succeed to to is only get elements at the first degree, so the elements which are not nested like account as you can see :

```
Client.get(Login.this, "user/login",headers2.toArray(new Header[headers2.size()]),entity,"application/json",
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
       @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response2) {   
                    Log.v("response",response2.optString("account"));
}
```

or in case of jsonArray response :

```
          public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                 Log.v("response",response.getJSONObject(0).toString());
}
```

also what i tried to do is transform jsonArray (because the web service response is in the array form) to hashMap so that i will access elements like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Object>>> result =
                                        new ObjectMapper().readValue((DataInput)response.getJSONObject(0), HashMap.class);
```

with **ObjectMapper** coming from **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper** and i tried to access like this :

```
result.get("account").get("user").get("userId")
```

but android studio answered me about **(DataInput) cast**

Comment: what do you want kindly clear your question.?

Comment: i would like to access to nested element of web service result with java (android), the format is jsonArray

Comment: i dont understand that brackets are start with array but end with object

Comment: it is because the web service response is too long, i can't paste all of it there, but it end with array @Adnanhaider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you get your json Array object of all type.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject account= object.getJSONObject("account");
    String accountId= account.getInt("0")       
    JSONObject accountType= account.getJSONObject("accountType");
    String accountType_Id=accountType.getString("accountTypeId");
    String libel=accountType.getString("libelle");
    JSONObject user=object.getJSONObject("user");
    String active= user.getString("actif");
    // and so on untiil profile come
    JSONObject profil= user.getJSONObject("profile");
    String code=response.getString("code");
    // and so on untril resource came
    JSONArray resources=user.getJSONArray("resource");
    for (int j = 0; j <resources.length() ; j++) {
        JSONObject resourceObject=resources.getJSONObject(j);
        String code= resourceObject.getString("code");
        // and so on until array end
        String status = object.getString("status");
        // and this is end
}  }
```

Comment: where does the variable **array** come from please? in the first line inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

you need to user Model class for each nested json block. like first you need Account type Model class which contains accountId named int variable and seconds is accountType model class like this :

```
Account{
int accountId;
AccountId accountType;// this is another model class 
}

AccountType{
int accountTypeId;
String libelle;
}
```

Comment: i dont understand, there is not the problem with make models, my problem is getting nested element inside REST API response with java